# python-apt package, obtain time pkg was installed and build time?

Tags: python, debian, apt

Is it possible to obtain the time a package was installed as well as the build time for that particular package?

For example:

```
import apt

def get_pkg_details():
    apt_cache = apt.Cache()
    selected_pkg = apt_cache["git"] #Example package

    time_installed = selected_pkg.installedTime() #?????
```

I know this is possible with RPM but I haven't found any documentation on anything similar to this on APT.

In RPM the install time of a package and build time can be accessed with the following enumerators:

```
RPMTAG_INSTALLTIME 
RPMTAG_BUILDTIME
```

python-apt Docs:
http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/i386_deb50/os/usr/share/doc/python-apt/html/apt/package.html#examples

RPM Tag API:
http://rpm.org/api/4.6.0/group__rpmtag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain part of a code that is distributed through an apt-server, so i have had to deal with this issue as well, for a basic idea of the time of build of a package I get the mtime [`os.path.getmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) of the package... `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE`

the line of my code also turns it into a datetime object.

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("PATH"))
```

Comment: This works if the pkg name is exact; I iterate packages installed in the system,  one by one i obtained the required information. Some don't match due to the name extensions, such as installed pkg "libopenal1", i get exception error because in  "/var/lib/dpkg/info", it shows as "libopenal1:amd64.shlibs". Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: @Dayan well, you can loop over each file in there and then you would have the install time of each package. or you could glob them with only packages in a name pattern you want, either way, getting the mtime of the file at that path will give you the package install time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the installation date use the following.

```
ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list -lah | grep packagename

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Dec 29 18:50 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-dev:i386.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.5K Dec 29 16:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K Dec 29 16:10 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-plugins:i386.list
```

As for compile date, you could look for the mtime of the package in /var/cache/apt/archives/